# How to place a table into a specific position within the body of mail sent using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code but I don't want my table to appear at the bottom of the body but instead in a specified place within the body of my email. I don't know VBA so I am struggling.

The email will be something like:

Dear Customer,

Paragraph 1

COPIED TABLE

Paragraph 2

Kind regards,

```
Sub Test_Click()

Dim outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

With newEmail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Test
    .Body = "Test"
    
    .display
    
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object

Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

Sheet1.Range("T45:X51").Copy

pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
pageEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

Set pageEditor = Nothing
Set pageEditor = Nothing

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing the `Selection.Start` location.   `Len(.Body)` counts the number of characters in the email body, so your selection is starting at the end of the body.  For example, to start the selection at the 5th character you can change it to `pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = 5`  If the preceding text length is not constant then you will need to identify the starting point with additional logic.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in such situation is to define a template for the email body, having variables at the place I want my data. And then I just to some replace()

Example:

```
Dim strTemplate as string
dim strVariable as string

strTemplate = "Dear Customer, " & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
              "Paragraph 1" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
              "[[COPIED TABLE]] " & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
              "Paragraph 2" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
              "Kind regards, " & vbcrlf 

strVariable = Sheet1.Range("T45:X51")


With newEmail
    .Body = Replace(strTemplate, "[[COPIED TABLE]]", strVariable)
```

much more easier, and you can deal that easily with any much variables/placeholders you want in your text